# Why do my test not run when executing as maven standalone test?

Tags: java, maven, testng

If I execute `mvn test`, all tests (written using TestNG) are execute correctly and passing. In some moments I want to execute a single test class with the typical `mvn test -Dtest=myClass`.

So basically when I try to launch a test from a specific class using the command `mvn test -Dtest=MyTests` I expect that only this class is executed. For some tests, is working fine, but if a tests class contains the following annotations to be executed with Spring:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
public class MyTests extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

@Test
public void test1(){
...
```

I get the output:

```
Running com.my.package.MyTests
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.215 sec - in com.my.package.MyTests
```

This class has two simple tests defined, and runs correctly with the `mvn test` but are ignored when `mvn test -Dtest=MyTests`. And only the ones with the previous annotations. Also the line `Running com.my.package.MyTests` makes clear that is finding the test class, but is not executed.

My TestNG version is 6.14.3. And its configuration is:

```
[...]
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
[...]
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/config/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
[...]
```

Why these test class is not executed?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show us your POM please so we can see if the tests configuration is correct.

Comment: Which Junit version are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question including the versions and all parts of the pom related to the testing phase.

Comment: You are not using the correct naming convention cause unit tests are by default named `*Test.java` and not `*Tests.java`. If you would use more recent versions of maven-surefire/failsafe this has been added (I'm not 100%sure which version exactly...